# Py2app app not launching just asks if I want to terminate the app or open console

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, py2app, .app

So I am working on a little project of mine that I want to distribute easily so naturally, I use py2app to make a single .app file that will execute on any Mac computer. I tried this tutorial: https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/. The problem is that even if I try the example that he gives in the tutorial it crashes and shows this window:
[Crash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzbzV.png) if I look in the console log of the event I see these tow errors.

> error 17:12:44.313837 +0100   Sandwich    Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
>
> error  17:12:44.472464 +0100   tccd    Failed to copy signing info for 3112, responsible for file:///Users/-myname-/folder/projects/SandwichApp/dist/Sandwich.app/Contents/MacOS/Sandwich: #-67062: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "(null)"

In case this is not enough info here is the code from the tutorial that I used:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sandwich")
tk.Button(root, text="Make me a Sandwich").pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

this is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Sandwich.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I have tried to add this to my setup.py in the OPTIONS because I saw other people had it, but the same thing keeps happening:

```
'argv_emulation': True
```

Any idea on what is going on?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been facing a problem with the exact same error code (-67062) and managed to resolve it at least for my machine running **Python 3.6.8** on **macOS 10.14.2**.

Open the file *../Sandwich/Contents/MacOS/Sandwich* and see the traceback message in Terminal. If tkinter imports are causing your issue like in my case, downgrade py2app via

> pip uninstall py2app

and use an older version, e.g.

> pip install py2app==0.12

and run py2app again. If you further encounter import problems of unwanted packages, e.g. pillow, you can exclude them with a workaround found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308771/py2app-crashes-with-pil-errors-on-earlier-versions-of-os-x)

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Sandwich.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    "excludes": ['pillow', 'Image'] # exclude unwanted dependencies
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Ronald Oussoren discussed debugging ImportErrors in py2app which can be found below for further reading:

https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/223/errors-on-compiling-in-py2app-i-have-all

Comment: Thanks, man. I ended up downgrading as you said and it worked perfectly.