# Creating a MAC app from a python script using py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I was trying to convert my python script ***test.py*** to a mac app.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAlkQEw8Gc).

Content of ***test.py***

```
print("Hello world!")
```

Then I created ***setup.py*** with the following content and saved in to the same folder as ***test.py***:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(app=APP, options={'py2app':OPTIONS},setup_requires=['py2app'])
```

Then I navigated my terminal to the folder where ***test.py*** and ***setup.py*** are stored.

Then I installed py2app with the following command(I am using Pycharm):

```
pip3 install py2app
```

Then I entered the following terminal command:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

py2app performed multiple operations and responded with

> Done!

I navigated back to the directory where ***test.py*** and ***setup.py*** are stored.

As expected, I found new directories: ***build*** and ***dist***.

I opened the ***dist*** directory and found a file ***test.app*** there.

I double clicked ***test.app***, an icon popped in the dock, bounced for few times, and disappeared.

*I did this with the simplest python script possible in order to figure out what the problem is. I tried to create and app from a more complex script before, in that case after double clicking the {}.app file a window poped app saying

> {file name} encountered and error

and let me choose to either terminate the app directly or see the console.

Please what am I doing wrong / is there a straightforward way to turn a py script into a mac app?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make the script interact with the user via a Terminal interface (e.g. using `print()` to send messages to the user, and `input()` to get input). But an app doesn't have a Terminal interface, so this won't work at all. If you want your Python script to function as a GUI app, you need to write it to function via a GUI, not via a Terminal interface. (Either that, or make it interfaceless, and just do things in the background.)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make the app from another script that uses tkinter and works perfectly when run in Pycharm. After running python setup.py py2app i get: **module 'plistlib' has no attribute 'Dict'**

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. As there is only a print in test.py, it's normal the app starts and disappears immediately.

You can put in test.py

```
import tkinter as tk
tk.Frame(tk.Tk()).mainloop()
```

build app and start it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to make the app not disappear immediately after it is initiated, I changed the code in **test.py** to  `txt = input("Hey, I will only disappear after you click \'Enter\'")`. I ran the `python setup.py py2app` terminal command again and run the app. What I got now is a dialog saying "test error".

Comment: Probably because app can not find terminal. Anyway it's a different problem now, maybe post another question ?

Comment: If it is certain that the problem is in OS/ terminal configuration, then agreed, it is a different problem. But I am unable to check whether this is the case or whether the py2app does not work properly. As I wrote above, I will be also grateful for any alternative suggestions how to turn a python script into a functional Mac app. I spent hours trying to find a viable solution but nothing seams to work properly. I am starting to think what is the point of learning python if you need a computer science phd to turn it into an app that actually works. Writing scripts rocks, but distribution too.

Comment: The `app` in my answer actually works. Have you tried that ?

Comment: I tried and (at least on my mac) it crashes immediately. As per below, it really appears to be a py2app issue. Some of them can be solved by downgrading py2app, for some of them I have not found any solution so far. I will keep looking, in either case, many thanks for taking the time to discuss this. Take care

Comment: The solution I gave worked on my MacOS/Big Sur. Can you double check the `pip3` matches `python` you used ? `python -V` and `pip3 -V`

Comment: Hey I had no idea the problem may be there. I checked pip3 and python versions as you suggested and the outcome is as follows: **pip3-V**: pip 21.0.1 from /Users/{my_sys_login}/{my_project_name}/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9), **python-V**: Python 3.9.2

Answer (score 0):

After further googling I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524071/py2app-app-not-launching-just-asks-if-i-want-to-terminate-the-app-or-open-consol) that discusses this problem. No that it would solve my problem, but maybe it will be helpful to somebody else.